# Dictionary key,value adding them

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

When i try to add the following from dictionary it shows the mismatch testcase output

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}
def dic_add(text):
    lower = text.lower()
    total = 0
    for c in lower:
        total += total + score[c]
    return total
dic_add("Pie")
```

It should return the *5* but the output is ***15***

ANY one help pls

Expected Output : *5*

Obtained Output : ***15***

Comment: just modify this `total += total + score[c]` to this `total += score[c]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `total += total + score[c]` you're increasing `total` twice. Use just `total += score[c]`

`total += score[c]` already means `total = total + score[c]`

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line:

```
total += total + score[c]
```

Either use:

```
total = total + score[c]
```

or:

```
total += score[c]
```

Comment: My answer is the same as J. Maria's, and came in a couple seconds later. I'm new to stackoverflow... what is the etiquette here? Should I delete my answer?